# Serialization and Deserialization of singleton obejct to nonsingleton object

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, singleton, deserialization

Is it possible to create a singleton class object in the client side, serialize it to the network stream and in the server side deserialize the object into same class just that in the server side it's not a singleton object?

Comment: What client side?  How are you serializing?  How do you intend to mirror the server-side?  This is a ridiculously vague question and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you're going to use a binary serializer because XML serialization would be best but requires a public parameterless constructor which would break your singleton.

You can use reflection to convert the singleton to XML and then parse it to the server... If your asking to send the binary of the object to the server and yet have it become an object that's not of the same type then you need to parse the information out either with reflection or by creating new objects.  Like the comment suggests it's a little vague but what I would do personally is pass the singleton properties into an XML object and send that to the server.  It's the easiest to work with although I understand binary serialization has performance gains.. It's just probably not worth the gain unless you're streaming.

So the short answer is no... You cannot serialize an object to only deserialize that same object and yet be a different object.  At best it would still be a singleton and some parsing would need to take place either way.